# how to optimize this below query in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, optimization, query-optimization

I have these tree tables in my project with large amount of data:

**core_department**: minimum 300,000 records

**app_user**: minimum 3,000 records

**app_user_department**: minimum 3,000 records

**app_user_excluded_department**: minimum 50 records

the `core_department` is department table that have a `hierarchy` for each records, this table data should be like this to store hierarchical data:

```
id  |title  |parentId   |hierarchy
-----------------------------------
1   |a      |null       |1
2   |b      |1          |1001
3   |c      |2          |1001001
4   |d      |3          |1001001001
5   |e      |3          |1001001002
```

I save the authorized departments of user into `app_user_department` and save unauthorized departments into `app_user_excluded_department`.

For example if the user should have access to **department a** and all of its child, i save this records into `app_user_department`:

```
userId  |deparmentId
--------------------
1       |1
```

and to exclude the **department c** and all of its child, save this record into `app_user_excluded_department`:

```
userId  |deparmentId
--------------------
1       |3
```

Finally, i call this below query to get all authorized departments of specific user:

```
create or replace view user_authorize as
    select dp.id, queryResult.userId
    from core_department dp
    join (
            select u.id as userId, dpt.hierarchy as hierarchy
              from app_user u
              join app_user_department udp
                on u.id = udp.userId
              join core_department dpt
                on udp.departmentId = dpt.id
    ) queryResult
    on dp.hierarchy like queryResult.hierarchy || '%'

    minus

    select dp.id, queryResult.userId
    from core_department dp
    join (
            select u.id as userId, dpt.hierarchy as hierarchy
              from app_user u
              join app_user_excluded_department udp
                on u.id = udp.userId
              join core_department dpt
                on udp.departmentId = dpt.id
    ) queryResult
    on dp.hierarchy like queryResult.hierarchy || '%'


select *
from user_authorize ua
where ua.userId = 1
```

How can i optimize this query?

Comment: get the explain plan, add indexes to the key columns, get the new explain plan and see if the indexes have helped

Comment: all of the tables have the Appropriate indexes

Comment: Why do you think it needs any further optimisation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the `WITH` clause, Oracle may create temporary a table and store such data in it. Thus the performance can be better:

```
create or replace view user_authorize as
WITH queryResult_1 as 
(            select u.id as userId, dpt.hierarchy as hierarchy
              from app_user u
              join app_user_department udp
                on u.id = udp.userId
              join core_department dpt
                on udp.departmentId = dpt.id
    ),
queryResult_2 as
(            select u.id as userId, dpt.hierarchy as hierarchy
              from app_user u
              join app_user_excluded_department udp
                on u.id = udp.userId
              join core_department dpt
                on udp.departmentId = dpt.id
    )
    select dp.id, queryResult_1.userId
    from core_department dp
    join queryResult_1 
    on dp.hierarchy like queryResult_1.hierarchy || '%'

    minus

    select dp.id, queryResult_2.userId
    from core_department dp
    join queryResult_2
    on dp.hierarchy like queryResult_2.hierarchy || '%'


select *
from user_authorize ua
where ua.userId = 1
```

Comment: A materialized common table expression only helps if the common table expression is used more than once.

Comment: What is *materialized common table expression*? could you give me more information about it?